# How to read data from a .csv file and store it in a table in openedge

Tags: csv, openedge

Could someone help me find a way to read data from a `.csv` file and then store it in a table in openedge.

```
INPUT FROM ‘c:\sample.csv’.
    REPEAT:
    CREATE customer.
    IMPORT DELIMITER "," cust-num name sales-rep.
    END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

This is the code that I tried but its not getting executed!

Comment: You need to provide the actual error message that you are getting along with the actual code that you are running.  FWIW "OUTPUT CLOSE." is not an error per se, but it is fairly odd (You never did an OUTPUT TO and there is no INPUT CLOSE.)

Answer (score 2):

The "\" is an "escape" character. Escape the escape by doubling it or (preferably) by using the alternate escape of "~".

Input from 'c:~\sample.csv'.

Comment: Hey, I tried using it but the error that's getting displayed is -  "Unable to understand after 'Import Delimiter' "

Comment: It's always helpful to provide error messages in the original post.  It is nice to know the version of Progress too.

Answer (score 2):

```
INPUT FROM c:\sample.csv.
REPEAT:
CREATE customer.
IMPORT DELIMITER "," customer.cust-num customer.name customer.sales-rep.
END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Remove the quotes from around your file name. Escape characters aren't needed for the blackslash since you are running on Windows and not Unix.

If you need to use a variable for the file name then you would use INPUT FROM VALUE(myvariable).

Comment: Quotes are necessary for Windows? In the case that the path has a space in it?

Comment: If you have spaces then you would need to add quotes or do the value part. Hopefully the OP will provide exact error messages with the new code so we can find out what the real issue is.

Comment: Not putting quotes around file names is an abomination.  Yes, it is "legal" syntax but it shouldn't be ;)

Comment: So is being able to reference column names without the table prefix :)